# How can I manipulate a list into a column?

Tags: python, list, doc

I have some output from a word file shown below:

```
Doc = docx2python('C:/Users/Sam/Data/Information.docx')
print(Doc.body[0])


[[['Event Info', '1)\tHalf (1 or 2)', '2)\tMinutes (on video)', '3)\tSeconds (on video)', '4)/tStaff, 0 = N/A)',]]]
```

I want to know how to put these lists into a column a shown the following output:

```
Event
Half
Minutes
Seconds
Staff
```

Comment: Is that an actual tab character `\t` or a literal backslash followed by a `t`?

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what were your results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Doc = docx2python('C:/Users/Sam/Data/Information.docx')
d=Doc.body[0]

# Putting some data into d for testing.
# Remove this for actual production.
d= [[['Event Info', '1)\tHalf (1 or 2)', '2)\tMinutes (on video)', '3)\tSeconds (on video)', '4)\tStaff, 0 = N/A)',]]]

# We'll need regular expressions.
import re

# Helper functions.

def startsWithADigit(x):
    return re.match(r"^[0-9]", x)

def getStuffAfterPotentialTabCharacter(x):
    return x.split("\t")[-1] 

def getFirstWord(x):
    return re.sub(r"([a-zA-Z]+).*", r'\1', x)


# Get rid of indented lists.
l=d[0][0]

# Get stuff after potential tab characters.
p=[getStuffAfterPotentialTabCharacter(x) for x in l]

# Get the first word in each record, as that seems to be requested.
q=[getFirstWord(x) for x in p]

# Print the result.
for x in q:
    print(x)
```

Comment: Variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.